# The integral $\int_0^1 \frac{z^j (1-z)^k}{j! k!} \, dz$

Tags: calculus

I am seeking help for a definite integral.
$\int_0^1 \frac{z^j (1-z)^k}{j! k!} \, dz$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)?

Answer (score 3):

Take a peek at the [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) :

$$\frac1{j!k!}\int\limits_0^1 z^j(1-z)^kdz=\frac{B(j+1,k+1)}{j!k!}=\frac{\Gamma(j+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{j!k!\Gamma(j+k+2)}$$

Thus, if for example $\;j,k\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\;$ , then

$$\frac1{j!k!}\int\limits_0^1 z^j(1-z)^kdz=\frac{j!k!}{j!k!(j+k+1)!}=\frac1{(j+k+1)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use integration by parts.  Taking u(z) = $z^j \hspace{10px} v'(z) = (1-z)^k$ you get

$ -z^j(1-z)^{k+1} \big |_0^1 + (j/(k_1)\int_0^1z^{j-1}(1-z)^{k + 1}dz$ = $\frac{1}{(j-1)!(k +1)!}\int_0^1 z^{j-1}(1-z)^{k + 1}dz$.

Continuing this way you will eventually have
$ \frac{1}{(k + j + 1)!} \int_0^1 (1-z)^{k + j}dz$ = 1/(k+ j + 1)!